# Partial indexing of an embedded document in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, query-performance, mongodb-indexes

I have the following data in a collection named `articles` :

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "id": "providercode",
      "value": "code1"
    },
    {
      "id": "otherAttribute",
      "value": "very long value than will be longer than 1024 bytes limit of an index value so I will get 'got unwanted exception: WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index'"
    },
    {
      "id": "objectAttr",
      "value": {
        "ican": "alsobeanobject"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the articles having "code1" in its providercode attribute.

I am searching with this query :

```
db.articles.find({ attributes: { $elemMatch: { "id": "providercode", "value": "code1" }}})
```

I need an index that will apply to the previous query.

**I tried this index :**

```
db.articles.ensureIndex({ "attributes.id": 1, "attributes.value": 1 })
```

It could work but it won't because of the potential very big strings in `attributes.value`.

I get the error :

`Error got unwanted exception: WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index`

**My question(s) is (are) :**

- is there a way to make a sort of partial index on my providercode attribute (indexing only the `providercode` part of the attributes) ?
- Is there a way to skip the indexing of an invalid (too long) `attribute.value` (like with mongodb < 2.6) ?

**Additional infos :**

- `providercode` value will always be a string short enough for an index
- each article document will have a providercode attribute
- I am with a mongodb 4.X

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in fact simple.

I made these indexes :

```
db.articles.ensureIndex({ "attributes.id": 1 });
db.articles.ensureIndex({ "attributes.value": "hashed" });
```

And my query is now using the index on `attributes.value`